# How To Delete A File Using MediaStore?

Tags: java, android

I just recently realized that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` has been depreciated in **Android Q**. I've done some research that the following code works when downloading pictures from the internet.

```
String fileName = String.format(imageName, System.currentTimeMillis());
File dir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyFolder").getAbsoluteFile();
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyFolder"));
Uri uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
assert uri != null;

scanFile(context, Uri.fromFile(dir));

try {
outStream = (FileOutputStream) cr.openOutputStream(uri);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Picture Download Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

dir.mkdirs();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to delete this picture file that the code above created in "MyFolder"

I tried the following codes but to no avail...

```
cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

***This works, but it deletes all picture files in "MyFolder" at once that was downloaded with the code above. I want it to delete the specified picture file corresponding with the fileName only. It should only delete one picture at-a-time.***

```
File picFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyFolder/" + imageName + ".png");
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse(picFile.toString());
cr.delete(deleteUri,null, null);
```

This doesn't work at all. It just crashes the app.
Any solutions? Thanks!

Here is the crash code...

```
2020-03-25 05:10:10.763 17371-17371/com.exampleproject.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.exampleproject.myapp , PID: 17371
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyFolder/The Late Late Show with James Corden.png
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1952)
        at com.exampleproject.myapp .MyAppPlayer$15.onClick(MyAppPlayer.java:1047)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:191)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7770)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

I just tried the following code. It doesn't crash the app, but it doesn't delete anything.

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
assert uri != null;
cr.delete(uri, null, null);
```

I feel like I am getting closer, but it's still not working. Here is what I changed it to from your example code... It doesn't crash the app, but the file still doesn't delete.

```
String fileName = String.format(imageName, System.currentTimeMillis());
File dir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyFolder").getAbsoluteFile();
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
String[] selArgs = new String[] {(myFile.getName())};
cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyFolder"));

cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", selArgs);
```

Comment: When you say "It just crashes the app" please provide the stack trace output of the crash. It is easier to specifically troubleshoot the issue if we know what the error received is.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nick Predey! I just edited my question, and I added the error crash report that you was wanting to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete specified picture :

Use

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

instead of

```
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyFolder/" + imageName + ".png"));
```

Because your file uri is something like this:

```
content://media/external/images/media/45
```

There is no delete uri, so you get this error "Unknown URL"

Delete func:

```
public Boolean deleteFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    String [] selectionArgs = {(file.getAbsolutePath())};
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String where = null;
    Uri filesUri = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        filesUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        where = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
        selectionArgs = new String[] {(file.getName())};
    } else {
        where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?";
        filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    }

    int result =  contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);

    return file.exists();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Kasim, but unfortunately that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I will add my delete code then you can change your code.

Comment: I've been trying. I think I am getting closer. I just added what I tried.

Comment: After 2 days of trying different ways to use your code with mine, I was able to finally get it! Thanks again Kasim!!

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work after reinstalling the app?